# Prob. 10, Sec. 19, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: For a family of functions $f_\alpha\colon A \to X_\alpha$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, open-map

Here is Prob. 10, Sec. 19, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $A$ be a set; let $\left\{ X_\alpha \right\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of spaces; and let $\left\{ f_\alpha \right\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of functions $f_\alpha \colon A \to X_\alpha$.
>
> (a) Show there is a unique coarsest topology $\tau$ on $A$ relative to which each of the functions $f_\alpha$ is continuous.
>
> (b) Let 
>   $$ \mathscr{S}_\beta = \left\{ \ f_\beta^{-1} \left( U_\beta \right) \ \vert \ U_\beta \mbox{ is open in } X_\beta \ \right\}, $$
>   and let $\mathscr{S} = \bigcup \mathscr{S}_\beta$. Show that $\mathscr{S}$ is a subbasis for $\tau$.
>
> (c) Show that a map $g \colon Y \to A$ is continuous relative to $\tau$ if and only if each map $f_\alpha \circ g$ is continuous.
>
> (d) Let $f \colon A \to \prod X_\alpha$ be defined by the equation 
>   $$ f(a) = \left( f_\alpha (a) \right)_{\alpha \in J}; $$
>   let $Z$ denote the subspace $f(A)$ of the product space $\prod X_\alpha$. Show that the image under $f$ of each element of $\tau$ is an open set of $Z$.

My Attempt:

Part (a):

> The discrete topology on $A$ makes each function $f_\alpha$ continuous; so the collection of all those topologies on set $A$ relative to each one of which each one of $f_\alpha$ is continuous is non-empty, and the intersection $\tau$ of these topologies is the coarsest topology on $A$ relative to which each $f_\alpha$ is continuous.

Is my argument correct?

Part (b):

> For each $\beta$, the set $X_\beta$ is open in $X_\beta$ and $f_\beta^{-1} \left( X_\beta \right) = A$ so that $A$ is in the collection $\mathscr{S}$. Thus $\mathscr{S}$ can be a subbasis for a topology on $A$; let $\tau^\prime$ be this topology. We show that $\tau^\prime = \tau$.
>
> Since each function $f_\beta$ is continuous relative to $\tau$, therefore the set $f_\beta^{-1} \left( U_\beta \right)$ is in $\tau$ whenever $U_\beta$ is an open set in $X_\beta$. Thus $\mathscr{S}_\beta \subset \tau$ and hence $\mathscr{S} \subset \tau$, and as $\tau$ is a topology, so $\tau$ contains the intersections of all the finite subcollections of $\mathscr{S}$ and hence $\tau$ also contains all possible unions of these intersections; that is, $\tau$ contains all the sets in $\tau^\prime$. Therefore $\tau^\prime \subset \tau$.

Is my argument correct?

> As $\mathscr{S}_\beta \subset \mathscr{S} \subset \tau^\prime$, so relative to the topology $\tau^\prime$ on $A$, each function $f_\beta$ is continuous;  but $\tau$ is the coarsest of all such topologies on set $A$. So we can conclude that $\tau \subset \tau^\prime$. Hence $\tau^\prime = \tau$, as required.

Is my argument correct?

Part (c):

> If the map $g \colon Y \to A$ is continuous relative to the topology $\tau$ on $A$, then as each map $f_\alpha \colon A \to X_\alpha$ is also continuous relative to the topology $\tau$, so each map $f_\alpha \circ g \colon Y \to X_\alpha$, being the composite of continuous functions, is also continuous.
>
> Conversely, if each map $f_\alpha \circ g$ is continuous relative to topology $\tau$ on $A$, then for each open set $U_\alpha$ in $X_\alpha$, the inverse image $\left( f_\alpha \circ g \right)^{-1} \left( U_\alpha \right)$ is open in $Y$. But 
>   $$ \left( f_\alpha \circ g \right)^{-1} \left( U_\alpha \right) = g^{-1} \big( f_\alpha^{-1} \left( U_\alpha \right) \big). \tag{0} $$
>
> Now let $V$ be any open set in $A$ relative to topology $\tau$. Then as $\mathscr{S}$ in Part (b) above is a subbasis for $\tau$, so our $V$ is a union of a collection of sets each of which is the intersections of some finite subcollection of $\mathscr{S}$; that is, $V$ is a union of sets, and  each of those sets ( whose union is $V$ ) is the intersection of finitely many of the sets of the form $f_\alpha^{-1} \left( U_\alpha \right)$, where $\alpha \in J$ and $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$.
>
> As unions and intersections are preserved under $g^{-1}$, so $g^{-1}(V)$ is a union of sets each of which is an intersection of some finite subcollection of the following collection of sets: 
>   $$ \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} \big\{ \ g^{-1} \left( f_\alpha^{-1} \left( U_\alpha \right) \right) \ \colon \ U_\alpha \mbox{ is opne in } X_\alpha \ \big\} = \bigcup \big\{ \ \left( f_\alpha \circ g \right)^{-1} \left( U_\alpha \right) \ \colon \ U_\alpha \mbox{ is opne in } X_\alpha \ \big\} . \tag{1} $$ 
>   Here we have used (0) above.
>
> As each of the sets in the collection (1) is open, so is any intersection of finitely many these sets and hence also any union of any of these intersections. Therefore $g^{-1}(V)$ is open in $Y$. Hence $g$ is continuous, as required.

Part (d):

> Let $U$ be an open set in $A$ relative to $\tau$. We need to show that $f(U)$ is open in $f(Z)$, that is, there is an open set $V$ in $\prod X_\alpha$ such that $f(U) = f(Z) \cap V$.
>
> Suppose $\mathbf{x} \in f(U)$. Then $\mathbf{x} = f(a)$ for some element $a \in U$ and so $\pi_\alpha ( \mathbf{x} ) = f_\alpha(a)$ for each $\alpha \in J$.
>
> Now as $U$ is opne in $A$ and as $a \in U$, so there is a basis subset $U^\prime$ for the topology of $A$ such that $a \in U^\prime \subset U$, and also $U^\prime$ is the intersection of some finite subsollection of the subbasis $\mathscr{S}$ for $\tau$; that is, there are $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in J$ such that $$ U^\prime = \bigcap_{i=1}^n f_{\alpha_i}^{-1} \big( U_{\alpha_i} \big),  \tag{1} $$
>   where $U_{\alpha_i}$ is open in $X_{\alpha_i}$ for each $i$. As for any $i = 1, \ldots, n$, and for any open sets $U_{\alpha_i}$ and $V_{\alpha_i}$ in $X_{\alpha_i}$, we note that 
>   $$ f_{\alpha_i}^{-1} \big( U_{ \alpha_i} \big) \cap f_{\alpha_i}^{-1} \big( V_{ \alpha_i} \big) = f_{\alpha_i}^{-1} \big( U_{ \alpha_i} \cap V_{ \alpha_i} \big), $$ 
>   which is again a set of the form which appears in the intersection on the right-hand-side of (1), so we can assume that the $\alpha_i$ in (1) are all distinct.
>
> For any $\alpha \in J$ such that $\alpha \neq \alpha_i$ for any $i$, we can take $U_\alpha$  to be $X_\alpha$. Then (1) takes the form 
>   $$ U^\prime = \bigcap_{\alpha \in J} f_\alpha^{-1} \big( U_\alpha \big), \tag{2} $$ 
>   where $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha \in J$ and $U_\alpha \neq X_\alpha$ for only finitely many $\alpha$.
>
> Then 
>   $$ \mathbf{x} = f(a) \in f \left( U^\prime \right) = f \big( \bigcap_{\alpha \in J} f_\alpha^{-1} \big( U_\alpha \big) \big) \subset  \bigcap_{\alpha \in J} f \big(  f_\alpha^{-1} \big( U_\alpha \big) \big). \tag{3} $$
>
> Also as $U^\prime \subset U$, so 
>   $$ f \left( U^\prime \right) \subset f(U). \tag{4} $$

Is what I have done so far correct? If so, then what next? How to proceed from here?

Comment: For (a) you mistaken. You are asked to show there is a   coarsest (weakest, smallest) topology on $A$ such that every $f_a$ is continuous. The discrete topology on $A$ is the finest (strongest, largest) topology on $A$ and every function on A is continuous with respect to the discrete topology.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet He doesn't say the discrete metric is the coarsest one, just that it shows there is a non-empty *intersection* of topologies. That's a correct argument.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. I apologize/

Comment: @DanielWainfleet it's quite alright. I just wanted to put the OP at ease as well

Answer (score 1):

(d) is false, AFAIK. It certainly holds if the subbasic elements actually already form a base, which happens iff the family of functions $f_\alpha$ separates points from closed sets. (see [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=1751.0001.0001.0001) for the argument of that last fact.
(i.e. for all $C \subseteq A$ closed and $x \notin C$ there is some $f_\alpha$ from our set of functions such that $f_\alpha(x) \notin \overline{f_\alpha[C]}$

So start looking for a counterexample... There is also some non-conclusive discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404541/critique-my-proof-from-munkres-product-topologies-chapter-2-section-19-proble) on that exact same subproblem.

For (c) just use that a map is continuous iff inverse images of *subbasic* elements are open. That's a bit shorter (and Munkres does prove this somewhere, so it's usable).

(a) and (b) are essentially OK, IMHO.